# Fill a ui view with live streaming video using VideoCore library

Tags: ios, uiview, streaming, live, videocore

I am using VideoCore library to capture and to live stream video to a server. I am using a square uiview to monitor the live stream on my app.  But I could not completely fill the view with my live streaming video output. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks. I am new to iOS development.

Here's my code:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "VCSimpleSession.h"
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *previewview;
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "VCSimpleSession.h"
@interface ViewController ()<VCSessionDelegate>


@end

VCSimpleSession *mysession;

UIImagePickerController *picker;

int *flag;

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize mybutton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    flag = 0;
    self.textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    mysession.delegate = self;

    self.previewview.hidden = NO;
    self.mybutton.hidden = NO;
    self.textfield.hidden = NO;

    [self.mybutton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [self.mybutton setTitle:@"Start streaming" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    mysession = [[VCSimpleSession alloc]initWithVideoSize:CGSizeMake(1280, 720) frameRate:30 bitrate:100000 useInterfaceOrientation:YES];

    mysession.previewView.frame = self.previewview.bounds;

    [self.previewview addSubview:mysession.previewView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my my problem solved.

In this line instead of 1280,720

```
mysession = [[VCSimpleSession alloc]initWithVideoSize:CGSizeMake(1280,720) frameRate:30 bitrate:100000 useInterfaceOrientation: YES];
```

I entered 480,850

```
mysession = [[VCSimpleSession alloc]initWithVideoSize:CGSizeMake(480,850) frameRate:30 bitrate:100000 useInterfaceOrientation: YES];
```

This got my problem solved. Now my ui view is filled with live camera feed.